# Image Isn't upating when going back to main activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-imageview, picasso

Ok, I've got two activities, in the main activity there is an image button that takes you to a profile page activity where you can click on another image button and access your photo gallery to set a profile picture which is saved into Firebase storage and as a url in the database. This all works, the problem is that after you do all this and go back to the main activity (I'm overriding the back button and starting a new main activity) the image button shows the previous profile image despite Log.d checks reporting that I am accessing the updated url. Even stranger, if I go into the profile activity again it will display the update profile pic and when I go back to the main activity again the new image will now be displayed correctly.

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.activity = this
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val emailer=intent.getStringExtra("passemail")

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.main_drawer_open, R.string.main_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        val profile = findViewById<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>(R.id.profilebutton)

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$emailer")

        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                Log.d("msg0 main", "image url: " + user!!.profile_pic);

                if(user!!.profile_pic.length > 0){

                        Picasso.get().load(user!!.profile_pic).into(profile)
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("msg0", databaseError.message) //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        }
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)

        profile.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, ProfilePage::class.java)
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent.putExtra("passemail",emailer)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

ProfileActivity

```
class ProfilePage : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var profilepic: de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    private lateinit var profileURi: Uri
    private lateinit var emailz: String

    private fun saveUserToDatabase(profilepicURL: String, emailer:String){

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$emailer/profile_pic")
        ref.setValue(profilepicURL)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("msg0", "saved pic to firebase database, $ref")

                }
                .addOnFailureListener{
                    Log.d("msg0", "failed to save pic into database, ${it.message}")
                }
    }

    private fun chooseImage() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE
        startActivityForResult(intent, 10)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val emailer=intent.getStringExtra("passemail")

        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            profileURi = data.data
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, profileURi)

            Log.d("msg0 profileuri", profileURi.toString());

            profilepic.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

            uploadImagetoFirebase(emailer);

        }
    }

    private fun uploadImagetoFirebase(emailer:String){

        if(profileURi == null) return
        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")
        ref.putFile(profileURi!!)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully uploaded image ${it.metadata?.path}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("msg0 upload", "image url: " + it.metadata?.path);


                    ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        Log.d("msg1 upload", "image url: " + it);

                        Toast.makeText(this, "File Location $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        saveUserToDatabase(it.toString(),emailer)
                    }
                }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity :: class.java)
        Log.d("checker2", emailz)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.putExtra("passemail",emailz)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_page)

        val emailer=intent.getStringExtra("passemail")
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        emailz = emailer

        //Create Image View and set it to call upload when clicked
        profilepic = findViewById<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>(R.id.img_profile)

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$emailer")

        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                Log.d("msg0 profile", "image url: " + user!!.profile_pic);

                if(user!!.profile_pic.length > 0){
                    Picasso.get().load(user!!.profile_pic).into(profilepic)
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("msg0", databaseError.message) //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        }
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)

        profilepic.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { chooseImage() })

    }
}
```

I'm using a library for the image buttons, but this problem existed before I added it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to start a new `MainActivity`, because

if you click back button, `ProfilePage` will be **destroy** and you will see the `MainActivity`.

If you `ValueEventListener` in `MainActivity` works, you will see the picture correctly.

Hope this help

Comment: I was running into this problem before trying to start a new MainActivity. I figured that when I pressed back I was taken to the MainActivity in its previous state and that's why the incorrect image was being shown, so I added the `intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` to clear it off the stack when moving to the profile activity and starting a new one when coming back to it, this didn't work though.

Comment: @Gianni you can put your emailz with `setResult` in ProfilePage , and get the emailz by `onActivityResult` in MainActivity